# How does this complicated shell command (containing |, && and sed) work?

Tags: linux, git, scripting

I'm trying to figure out how to work git filter-branch and I need help with some basic Linux scripting commands.

```
'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t-&newsubdir/-" |
                GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                        git update-index --index-info &&
         mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE' HEAD
```

Can anyone break this down for me and explain each part?

I'm most interested in the '|' notation, the && notation, and the sed command.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case, but in general there are multiple script languages in linux. The first line of the file should tell you which one, you need to include that information in your question.

Comment: @John: This snippet is probably in a git control file, which means that the specific shell is either already well defined or is completely unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|` connects stdout of the preceding command to stdin of the following command.

`&&` executes the following command if the return code of the preceding command is 0 (that is, the command succeeded).

The `s` command in sed is a **substitution**. It searches for a regex match for the first argument and replaces it with the second. The argument separator is traditionally `/`, but it will use the first character that follows, `-` in this case. The `&` in the replacement is replaced with the entire match.

Comment: Thanks!

So just to clarify:

The very first command will list the files, from that output sed will replace \t with "newsubdir" and then the output from sed will be set as the new $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new.

Comment: Not quite. sed will replace `\t` with `\tnewsubdir`, then will pipe it into `git update-index --index-info`, and if that succeeds will rename a file. The prologue to `git update-index` is used to define an environment variable only for the execution of the command.

Comment: Won't the result of `sed` be piped to `GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new` first before `git update-index --index-info`?

Comment: No, because `GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new` is not the command; it merely modifies the actual command that follows. The `\\` is used to continue the command on the next line (it "escapes the newline").

Answer (score 1):

"|" is the unix pipe command which connects the command on the left sides output to the command on the right side's input.


"&&" is the unix "and" command which will execute the command on its right if and only if the command on it's left completes successfully


"sed" is the unix "stream editor" a powerful editing tool which parses and edits it's input